# How much "play" is normal in a Sturmey Archer 3 speed hub?

Tags: hub, internally-geared-hub

I inherited a bike with a Sturmey Archer 3 speed hub (Sturmey Archer AW, from 1984).

I am very familiar with free-wheels and cassete hubs, but this is fairly new to me, although I did some research on the internet, I couldn't find anywhere that had a hub spinning.

In my case, I am probably going to disassemble it (I have seen some videos, it won't be easy but is doable).

Finally, the question:

I noticed that there is a (IMO) fairly big amount of "play" (is this the term?) when I rotate the cog counter-clockwise (direction of coasting) and then rotating clockwise (drive).

I would say it is about 2 cm of "play".

Is the amount shown here too much, or is this normal?
[Animated gif showing the hub play](http://imgflip.com/i/142f2)

Comment: No letter codes? http://sheldonbrown.com/english-3.html#sturmey 
I think most of the SA two speeds were Duomatic, with a kickback gear change, but your GIF has a indicator rod and change, so it's not one of them.
And a fair amount of lash/play before the pawls engage is usual.

Comment: @armb nice one, I didn't catch those letters, in my case it says AW, and I know now that it is a three speed hub, corrected on the question. You mean the play displayed is acceptable?

Comment: I wouldn't swear that much normal and not a sign of stuck pawls, but if it reliably does engage when you pedal forwards I expect it's okay. I'll see if I can find one and compare. Knowing it's an AW will lead you to hundreds of dismantling and servicing guides, I've never been that brave....

Comment: Thanks, I don't know anyone else with a SA, so if you can try one I would be gratefull. I'm anxious to disasemble it, it will be a fun experience, especially the assembly (the tough part) :)

Comment: Found one, and the pawls aren't engaging at all so it spins round in both directions with no drive :-( There's another one in the shed somewhere, with Dynohub.

Comment: @armb can you check a functional one? also write the answer here saying what is the normal play of the hub, and I'll accept it.

Comment: After disassembling, did you find any way to fix the 'play' issue? Mine is doing the same thing on an AW sturmey. It's for a rejuvenation project and want it working like new. If you found a fix it would be great to hear it.

Comment: @DavidBriggs I haven't disassembled it yet. I am going to do it at the end of this month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't find my working three speed hub, but from memory, and from trying a working five speed, then as far as I can tell from the gif, that's normal.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to disassemble it any way, but it's good to have this "confirmation".

Answer (score 0):

AW means “always works”. That play seems normal.

Comment: Is there a source for the AW claim or is it inferred?